# oracle missing right parenthesis (Line 7)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Im trying to create a constraint to ensure to columns are different values but keep getting an error on the timesheet_approved line.

```
create table Funtom_timesheet 
(
timesheet_ID          number(3) constraint timesheet_pk primary key,
timesheet_Emp         number(3) constraint timesheet_Emp not null references funtom_employee,
timesheet_Wc          date      constraint timesheet_Wc not null,  
timesheet_OT          number(2) default 0,
timesheet_Approved    number(3) constraint timesheet_approved_uc unique(timesheet_Approved,timesheet_Emp) constraint timesheet_approved references funtom_employee 
)
;
```

Comment: Check the create table syntax at [Techonthenet](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table.php), [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think multi-column constraints are not part of the column definition.  Try separating them out:

```
create table Funtom_timesheet (
    timesheet_ID          number(3) constraint timesheet_pk primary key,
    timesheet_Emp         number(3) constraint timesheet_Emp not null references funtom_employee(??),
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
    timesheet_Wc          date      constraint timesheet_Wc not null,  
    timesheet_OT          number(2) default 0,
    timesheet_Approved    number(3),
    constraint timesheet_approved_uc unique(timesheet_Approved,timesheet_Emp),
    constraint timesheet_approved references funtom_employee(??)
-------------------------------------------------------------^
);
```

And fill in the column for the references

Comment: that has gotten rid of the initial error however now I have an error saying unknowncommand")"